# Create CAMPAIGN from AMPScript / SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I want to create CAMPAIGN from Landing Page. All I know is it's impossible with just AMPScript. So, I have to use SSJS.

After looking on [SSJS documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) I couldn't find any dedicated CAMPAIGN function. I not sure if it's:

`var newObject = Platform.Function.CreateObject("?????");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way is via an [API call or using an SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/campaign-create.htm). I can find no documentation on how to do this outside of these instances.

In that vein though, through SSJS or even AMPscript you can make a [POST](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49588/best-way-to-make-http-requests), allowing you to use the REST API.  So, if you build your call in these languages, you can make your [REST API call to build or manipulate a campaign](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html#campaigns).

**EDIT**: Updated link to new SDK link as shown in comment.

Comment: The URL changed.  Here's the new URL
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/campaign-create.htm